# how to play an audio file - .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I want to play a sound on my mobile application (android and IOS) I play a sound in certain circumstances. How can I do it?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7152

Comment: GErald Versius has a recent video explaining how to do this

Comment: Consider changing the accepted answer to [antonio's more recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75468324/199364).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.NET Maui (feb,2023), still in preview on VS2022.

There is another way to play audio/video (mp3/mp4) in .NET MAUI:
**MediaElement** control of Communitytoolkit with support for Android/iOS/Windows/Tizen/Mac.

Use NuGet to install, search for '**CommunityToolkit.Maui.MediaElement**'.

Put local files in "Resources/Raw" with BuildAction=MauiAsset

```
xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
```

Inside a contentPage (xaml/c#)

```
<toolkit:MediaElement x:Name="correctMediaElement" IsVisible="false"
            Source="embed://crrect_answer2.mp3" />

internal static void PlaySound(MediaElement me)
{
    var preset = MauiProgram.Preset;
    if (me.CurrentState != CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core.Primitives.MediaElementState.Stopped &&
        me.CurrentState != CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core.Primitives.MediaElementState.Paused)
    {
        me.Stop();
    }
    if (preset != null)
    {
        switch (preset.BuzzerVolume)
        {
            case Volume.Off:
                me.Volume = 0.0;
                break;
            case Volume.Low:
                me.Volume = 0.2;
                break;
            case Volume.Medium:
                me.Volume = 0.7;
                break;
            case Volume.High:
                me.Volume = 1.0;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    if (me.Position != TimeSpan.Zero)
    {
        //Will Play sound here
        me.SeekTo(TimeSpan.Zero);
    }
    else if (me.CurrentState != CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core.Primitives.MediaElementState.Playing)
    {
        me.Play();
    }
}
```

for more information:
[MediaElement doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/mediaelement)
[DevBlogs.Microsoft.com](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-dotnet-maui-communitytoolkit-mediaelement/)

Answer (score 7):

**Playing AUDIO in MAUI APP Made Easy with 2 Plugins:**
In NuGet Packages Manager Install the following and Use Dependency Injection After Installation!

1. **Plugin.Maui.Audio**: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.Maui.Audio/
2. **Plugin.MauiAudio**: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.MauiAudio/

Comment: Plugin.Maui.Audio worked great for me. I added it through Nuget in Visual Studio.
https://github.com/jfversluis/Plugin.Maui.Audio

Comment: Good   to See that

Comment: I assume this preview solution is now obsolete. See [antonio's more recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75468324/199364) for discussion of MediaElement. That should be the accepted answer now.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, Maui does not have any audio playback framework. And there are some relative known issues in maui, you can follow them here:

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7152 .

https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/issues/113

Comment: This answer might be obsolete. See [antonio's more recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75468324/199364), which discusses `MediaElement control of Communitytoolkit`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I added audio capability, note that I used MAUI Blazor in .NET 6 when I tested.

Add Nuget package :

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Plugin.Maui.Audio" Version="2.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Inside MauiProgram.cs , add the service

```
using Plugin.Maui.Audio;

namespace MultiLingual.Translator;

public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
            });

        builder.Services.AddMauiBlazorWebView();
        #if DEBUG
        builder.Services.AddBlazorWebViewDeveloperTools();
#endif

        builder.Services.AddSingleton(AudioManager.Current);

        //more code  ..
```

Important bit is -

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton(AudioManager.Current);
```

Inside a MAUI page, just inject the AudioManager next, I inject it in the razor file.

```
@inject IAudioManager AudioManager
```

If you want to inject it via DI, pass it into the constructor of the code behind instead.

Playing an audio file is then done as in my example here, in my sample code I have written a text to speech demo and I have downloaded a voice file from Azure AI Cognitive Services - Speech service. The array *VoiceData* contains a byte array which I play after first writing the file into the appdata folder.

```
 var voiceFolder = Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory, "Resources", "Raw");
        if (!Directory.Exists(voiceFolder))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(voiceFolder);
        }
        string voiceFile = "textToSpeechVoiceOutput_" + Model.TargetLanguage + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") + ".mpga";
        string voiceRelativeFile = Path.Combine(voiceFile);

        string voiceFileFullPath = Path.Combine(voiceFolder, voiceFile);
        await File.WriteAllBytesAsync(voiceFileFullPath, textToSpeechResult.VoiceData);
        Stream voiceStream = File.OpenRead(voiceFileFullPath);

        StateHasChanged();

        var player = AudioManager.CreatePlayer(voiceStream);
        player.Play();
```

The important bit is the last two lines, we create a file stream and create a player instance via *AudioManager.CreatePlayer* metod passing in the stream.
Then we just call the *Play* method to play the audio. You can have multiple player instances and for example play multiple sounds at once, if desired.

Important bit is -

```
   var player = AudioManager.CreatePlayer(voiceStream);
   player.Play();
```

The audio I tested was this format :

```
audio-24khz-48kbitrate-mono-mp3
```

Not very complex to get started with Audio in .NET MAUI in other words. If you have audio that requires certain libs/codecs, the lib might not support this.

Website of Plugin.Maui.Audio is here:
https://github.com/jfversluis/Plugin.Maui.Audio

Answer (score 1):

1. Add the [Plugin.Maui.Audio](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.Maui.Audio/) Nuget Package

   ```
   <PackageReference Include="Plugin.Maui.Audio" Version="2.1.0" />
   ```
2. Add the following line to the `MauiProgram.cs`

   ```
   builder.Services.AddSingleton(AudioManager.Current);
   ```
3. Add the sound file under the `Resource/Raw` folder (mp3, wav, ..)

   [image]
4. Set the `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy if newer` for the sound files

   [image]

5. Play the sound like this

   ```
   IAudioManager audioManager; // inject this from constructor
   Stream track = FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("cardtrack").Result;
   IAudioPlayer player = audioManager.CreatePlayer(track);
   player.Play();
   ```

   and you can inject `IAudioManager` and use it.

---

**Notes**

1. The package is maintained by a Microsoft Engineer
2. Here is a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oIYnEuZ9oew) that explains it

Comment: Thanks for breaking that down. The legacy Xamarin functionality required the sounds to be compiled in the project assembly, then extracted to play during runtime (GetManifestResourceStream()). This did not work in Maui

Answer (score 0):

Should use "file:///storage/..." instead of "filesystem:///storage/..." to read local media in android.