# How to play a mp3 audio stored in a byte array in MAUI .NET

Tags: audio, byte, mp3, maui

I have in a database some MP3 sounds and I read and store its in a byte[] variable.
My question is, How can I play de audio stored in the byte[] variable in .NET MAUI?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to play an audio file - .NET MAUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72463558/how-to-play-an-audio-file-net-maui)

Comment: You can check this case: [DOTNET Maui playing audio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/823706/dotnet-maui-playing-audio).

Comment: I will try its en a couple of days, Thanks a lot.